# Why does the script embedded in the callback run first in this example?

Tags: javascript, callback

I would like to understand why does the alert for script2 popup first  in this specific case? If I uncomment the setTimeout within the base function declaration, script1 alerts first. 
I was expecting that with or without the setTimeout, within the base function, script1 would alert first. A clarifying answer would be much appreciated.

```js
function base(src, cb) {
  //setTimeout(() => {
  cb();
  alert(src + ' finished executing')
  //}, 100)
}

function first() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('first');
  }, 110)
}

function second() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('second');
  }, 110);
}

base('script 1', () => {
  first();
  base('script 2', () => {
    second();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function first() is executed before second() but the alert is generated after executing both because you have encapsulated both into the callback method. And the alert is generated after completing the whole function. Maybe you should write your code in following way to understand what happens.

```
function base(src, cb) {
  //setTimeout(() => {
  cb();
  alert(src + ' finished executing')
  //}, 100)
}

function first() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('first');
  }, 110)
}

function second() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('second');
  }, 110);
}

base('script 1 and script 2', () => {
  base('script 1', () => {
    first();
  });
  base('script 2', () => {
    second();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code invokes the `base()` function, passing in a function that also calls `base()`.  Thus the "second" function finishes first, because the nested call to `base()` invokes it before it posts the `alert()` for the "first" function.

Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.